# problem building Mutis demo (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

I'm using CodeGear RAD Studio 2009.
I want to use the Mutis text search engine. Download from SourceForge seems to lack documentation, so I tried to build the included BasicDemo. Doesn't build, gives a series of errors "missing implementation for abstract method...". Does anyone have a working version?
TIA
Steven

PS: for what I remember about abstract methods is that implementation is only required on the inherited level. Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about abstract methods. The author created methods in the base class marked as abstract but didn't create an implementation of them in the derived classes.

I followed this project since the beginning and even tried to help. It lacks a critical mass of users. I suggest you to look for alternatives. The last file that was released is 4 years old and the last activity in the SVN repository is 2 years old.